# Telerik MVC Window jquery validator issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, telerik

I try validate my form, which load in window with Ajax.
But, don't work:

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#myform");
```

Problem solved, if

1)I include jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js files in partial view, where is form

2) or I include js. file in DefaultGroup(but this old solution 2010 Q2 http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/preview-thread/aspnet-mvc/grid/client-side-validations-with-mvc-3-don-t-work.aspx )
My question is how today it's my problem solve optimally.
Thanks. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Either approach is valid, as they essentially end up doing the same thing, but to ensure that you have the same JavaScript functionality across all the views it might be the easiest to just include the script manually in the ScriptRegistrar. For more information on all of this you can refer to [this documentation article](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/web-assets-working-with-javascript-web-assets.html).